# FastAPI - Best way to run continuous GET requests in the background

Tags: python, celery, fastapi

I am trying to create a program which does periodic GET requests from around 10 websites and updates the information in a DB locally. Now when a user wants information, I will display the locally stored aggregate info.

I am trying to figure out the best way to run these periodic GET requests in FastAPI. I am new to FastAPI and am still trying to figure things out.

After some research I can think of two options:

1. Using a background task endpoint which runs periodically and does the GET requests one by one from each website.
2. Using Celery to do these GET requests

If anyone has any experience of doing something similar I am trying to figure out the best way to do this, or how would I go about finding out the best way to do this?

Comment: Just checking.  FastAPI is used to build web sites.  If this is a background task that is independent of incoming requests, then it doesn't need FastAPI.  It can just be a periodic `cron` job that does a series of requests using the `requests` module.  Right?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense as well thanks. Since I am using FastAPI for the website itself, I thought that using fastAPI for this particular purpose makes sense since it already has DB connectivity in the app and things like that. But I will consider using this as well. Thank you

Comment: Future readers might benefit from the following answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that for that Celery is overkill for one periodic task. Celery requires a broker (and preferable backend as well). Are you going to bringup/manage RabbitMQ only for a single task?

A simpler solution can be using `asyncio` for that:

```
TIME_INTERVAL_IN_SEC = 60


async def crawl_websites():
    while True:
        # async GET requests
        # async update DB
        await asyncio.sleep(TIME_INTERVAL_IN_SEC)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(crawl_websites())
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try this approach. The way I understand it, if I run this block within fastAPI, it will run in the same event loop as the rest of the backend functionality. So you would suggest that I run this from a script outside of fastAPI or it would not make any difference if I run it from within fastAPI?

Comment: You can run within fast API, there is also a discussion about that here: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/543